# Environment variables passed by Runtime.exec(String)

Tags: java

Are the environment variables of the parent process(e.g. shell) available in the environment in which a child process that is invoked using Runtime.exec(command) run? I had a look at the API documentation but it's not specified there.

My use case is this

`mainScript.sh` invokes `java MainClass`

`MainClass` invokes `Runtime.exec("hi.sh")`

Now, is a variable `MY_ENV` that is set and exported in `mainScript.sh` available to `hi.sh`?

PS: I'm aware of the 2nd API that takes explicit `String[] envp`.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4064912 has some vague info.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I tried it and the answer was 'Yes, it passed it'. But I want a concrete answer, something not based on mere experimentation.

Comment: The runtime would have to go to some pains to *not* convey environment variables, and doing so would potentially make launched processes fail (due to missing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or just `PATH` for that matter), so I think it's safe to rely on the environment working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, why not?

From Runtime [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html):

> Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running